# Set Google Maps on another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I am Creating Wizard For One of My Application In which user Have to give details.The problem occurs when i Put My google map in fragment.please note that i have framelayout in which i put fragment and in that fragment i want to have maps please help me...

here my Code:

**FragmentActivity Class**

```
public class IntroDuction_Main extends FragmentActivity
.................
.......... 
F_map map=new F_map();
            map.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            Transectionfragment(map);
}
private void Transectionfragment(Fragment frag) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
            android.R.anim.fade_out, android.R.anim.fade_in,
            android.R.anim.fade_out);
    transaction.replace(R.id.MainFragment, frag);

    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

**Layout of Fragment Activity**

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lat_lng"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="80">
</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="Button" />
```

**Map Fragment class**

```
    package in.high_tech.foodonclick.Introduction;

import in.high_tech.foodonclick.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class F_map extends Fragment {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Bundle mBundle;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_map, container, false);
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            // TODO handle this situation
        }
        MapView mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mMapView.onCreate(mBundle);
        setUpMapIfNeeded(view);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBundle = savedInstanceState;
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded(View inflatedView) {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (mMap != null) {
                // setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Layout Of fragment class**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:mapType="normal" />
```

Here's My Logcat

```
    07-11 04:45:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(361): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 04:45:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(361): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
07-11 04:45:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at in.high_tech.foodonclick.Introduction.F_map.onCreateView(F_map.java:31)
07-11 04:45:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
07-11 04:45:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
07-11 04:45:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
07-11 04:45:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-11 04:45:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
07-11 04:45:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:450)
07-11 04:45:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-11 04:45:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-11 04:45:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
07-11 04:45:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
07-11 04:45:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 04:45:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-11 04:45:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
07-11 04:45:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-11 04:45:45.242: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 04:45:45.258: D/dalvikvm(361): GC_CONCURRENT freed 122K, 16% free 8728K/10308K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 21ms
```

Comment: I did something similar. Are you putting different fragments in different tabs?

Comment: No i am not having tabs but when i click on next button the view of fragments are chenging there are actually 3 more fragments.i am replacing it every time on next button click

Comment: Yes with null point exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Solution.i just used mapview in my layout